# Protein Biology Cheat Sheet

Tags: proteins

I'm looking find a cheat sheet for protein biology to stick on my desk to remind of some of the key principles of protein biology. I seem to remember the specific and complex principles in protein biology but at the expense of the basics.

Can anyone point me to a protein biology cheat sheet or formulate some suggestions to go on one?

---

EDIT

What I am looking for:

- Amount of amino acids in a helix turn
- Amino acids typically found in Beta sheets and Helices
- The types of protein interactions (i.e. ionic, hydrophobic) and the  amino acids usually involved.
- Definition of Globular and fibrous form
- Types of post-translational modifications
- Any other useful characteristics

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This question may be too vague to be reasonably answered here. I would suggest by starting to read an entry-level molecular or cell biology textbook. Perhaps you could more specifically narrow down which subset of protein chemistry you are looking for a cheat sheet on. For example, amino acid properties, classes of protein structures and functions, post-translational modification.

Comment: Related: a friend of mine created this [*periodic table* of aminoacids](http://www.molecularlab.it/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=5342). The original is in Italian, but an English translation is attached at the end of that forum post. Also, svg sources are available and it is under a BY-NC-SA CC license so you can modify/expand it to your liking.

Answer (score 4):

For 95% of the work I do with protein, I find this [chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aGeneticCode22.svg) very helpful, showing common post-translational modifications, for each amino acid, with molecular weights, associated codons, pKa values, 1- and 3-letter amino acid codes, chemical structure and chemical properties (polar, non-polar, aromatic, acidic, basic).

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a question about what else should be on a protein cheat sheet.

If you are clever you can format this to have a very high density of information. A good project.

Here's my list - I never made a sheet though.  Also I tend to be interested in protein structure, so there's a bias here.

- The frequency of the amino acids in say e coli or the PDB
- The average molecular weight of an amino acid (~110 daltons)
- avg backbone width of a sheet (5 x 6 Ang) and helix (12 Ang.) DNAMajor groove is also 12 Ang btw.
- common non standard amino acids (ornithine, seleneomet, etc).
- common post translational modifications (e.g. T/Y phosphorylation)
- common non standard secondary structure (3-10 helix etc) or a small ramachandran diagram
- pKas of amino acids - remember that charge is defined at pH 7
- the genetic code

For alpha/beta propensities, I would use chou-fasman's numbers.  Its annoying because there are some amino acids in *both* lists.

I will try to think of more and add later...

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in any university-level biochemistry textbook.

I would recommend you [Lehninger Principles of Biochemistry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/071677108X), if you could find it in your university library.

Skim the list of content, find corresponding chapters and write it down. It won't take you several hours.